# How to write items with two different categories

Tags: itemize, enumitem, subitem

I want to write items in the following form:

- 1.1
- 1.2
- 1.x
- 2.1
- 2.2
- 2.y

and so on. My problem is with increments on the left and right side. Is there any way to write this without doing the increments manually?

Comment: It is possible, but can you explain in detail what you meant by ` increments on the left and right side`?

Comment: The left side in x.y I mean x. I want x to not always increment (like a section), and y (like a subsection) to increment from 1 and reset when x becomes x+1 and so on. Am I clear?

Comment: ... Am I clear? ... No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you expect like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlist{label*=\textbf{\thesection. \arabic*.}}

\section{Test}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First entry
    \item Second entry
    \item Third entry
    \end{enumerate}


\section{Test}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First entry
    \item Second entry
    \item Third entry
    \end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ur most welcome...

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín Err ..., really you want items labelled as subsections ...or just subsections? Maybe `\section{Test} \subsection{Fist entry } ....?`. It could look similar to a nested list in bold  font, but is very different. If you want The items with a tittle and associated text below, then you want subsections, not `enumerate`  environments.